# How can I return the min/max value of a measure in a specified filter context?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a report with several measures, each of which are presented in visualisations that include a Fiscal Year dimension.

My requirement is to return the minimum and/or maximum value of these measures for each possible Fiscal Year in another measure, i.e. without having to include the Fiscal Year dimension in the visualisation.

My data is in a flat table:

```
ForecastName    FiscalYear  TransactionType Value
Forecast1      2019         borrowing       10
Forecast1      2020         borrowing       10
Forecast1      2021         borrowing       10
Forecast1      2022         borrowing       20
Forecast1      2023         borrowing       25
Forecast2      2019         borrowing       30
Forecast2      2019         turnover        40
Forecast3      2019         turnover        50
Forecast3      2020         turnover        50
```

An example of one of the measures (although some are rather more complex):

```
Borrowing = CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Value]),Table[TransactionType]="borrowing")
```

Visualising this 'Borrowing' measure in a table with Fiscal Year on the rows and 'Forecast1' selected in a slicer on ForeastName returns these values:

`10, 10, 10, 20, 25`

What I would like is a measure that returns:

```
25 (ForecastName slicer = 'Forecast1')
30 (ForecastName slicer = all values)
```

I think need a dynamic table that returns all the values I need inside a measure,  and then pass the relevant column to MAX?

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with a similar matter. In my case, I have a table with scores (and other things) *for each week of each year*. And for the Power BI report, I only wanted the record for the highest week in a given year. To do so, I just used filters for the report. The filter called **Type N** can return the highest or the lowest value (or values) if you desire.

[image]

If you do **not** want to see `year` in your report, that's okay. Just delete the `year` icon from the **Visualizations** area. The filter will remain.

Comment: Thanks Joe. That does work but I think for only one measure - I know there's a TOPN function tho so maybe that could work.

Comment: @deethreenovice - You are very welcome. And that is correct. The Top N filter can only be used on 1 field. In this case, I've built a **dashboard** that is a collection of different reports. It has several KPI's such as the **lowest** scores & the **highest** scores together on the same display.